# Finding import and dependency with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use imageResource in an Android Jetpack Compose app but I cannot find the depndency to add to my grade file.

imageResource is in the docs here:

[androidx.compose.ui.res](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap.Companion).imageResource(android.content.res.Resources,kotlin.Int))

```
Image(
    bitmap = imageResource(id = R.drawable.background),
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
)
```

When I add androidx.compose.ui.res to my grade file it fails to resolve.

How do I find the dependency to add to my grade file for immageresouzrce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No dependency, the link you posted clearly states the method is accessible though `ImageBitmap.Companion.imageResource(...)`, so that is what it is.

Type the exact phrase and you'll be good.

Explicitly using the `Companion` property is not necessary, you could directly use `ImageBitmap.imageResource(...)` here as well.

Comment: A helpful tip, if you didn't know, is starting to type a name and hitting `Ctrl` + `Space` in Studio to pop up / refresh the code completions list. Also, press `Ctrl` + `P` to view all the available parameters that you can pass to a method call.